# Selecting elements within a table with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select an id inside my table for each row.

This is my table(inspected with browser) at the moment.

```
<table id="sort">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Pri </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

                        <tbody style="cursor: n-resize; " class="ui-sortable"><tr class="priorityRow">
                            <td id="tableDragSort">
                                <a class="deleteLink" href="#" rel="17904" title="">
                                 <img src="/Content/Images/Garage/DeleteButton.png"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_CarImg_0" class="17904" src="" style="height:45px;width:60px;">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainColContent$ImageRepeater$ctl00$txtText" type="text" value="hjjj" id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_txtText_0">
                            </td>
                            <td class="picturePriority">
                                1
                            </td>
                        </tr><tr class="priorityRow" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 0; ">
                            <td id="tableDragSort" style="width: 22px; ">
                                <a class="deleteLink" href="#" rel="17903" title="">
                                 <img src="/Content/Images/Garage/DeleteButton.png"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 60px; ">
                                <img id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_CarImg_1" class="17903" src="" style="height:45px;width:60px;">
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 153px; ">
                                <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainColContent$ImageRepeater$ctl01$txtText" type="text" value="dd" id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_txtText_1">
                            </td>
                            <td class="picturePriority" style="width: 21px; ">
                                2
                            </td>
                        </tr><tr class="priorityRow" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 0; ">
                            <td id="tableDragSort" style="width: 22px; ">
                                <a class="deleteLink" href="#" rel="17895" title="">
                                 <img src="/Content/Images/Garage/DeleteButton.png"></a>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 60px; ">
                                <img id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_CarImg_2" class="17895" src="" style="height:45px;width:60px;">
                            </td>
                            <td style="width: 153px; ">
                                <input name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainColContent$ImageRepeater$ctl02$txtText" type="text" value="wggw" id="MainContent_MainColContent_ImageRepeater_txtText_2">
                            </td>
                            <td class="picturePriority" style="width: 21px; ">
                                3
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                  </table>
```

The id which here is `17904`, `17903` and `17895` in both `<a rel="">` and `<img class="">` is the one I want to select into my javascript method which is here:

```
$("#sort .priorityRow").each(function ()
    {
        var index = $(this).index() + 1;


        var id = /* SELECT ID HERE */

        console.log(id);
        $(this).find(".picturePriority span").text(index);
        SetPicturePriority(id, index);
    });
}
```

I don't care which way i select the id really, as long as it works.

Anyone able to help? :)

Comment: It's not valid to use duplicate IDs on a page.

Comment: The img id will not be duplicated. Its dynamic

Comment: Does not seem to matter as it works on another site. But, the problem here is the selecting of the img id, not the ids on the table

Comment: What ID? The numbers are on the rel attribute. `var id = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like *maybe* you're trying to do this:

```
$("#sort .priorityRow").each(function () {
    var rel = $(this).find("a").first().attr("rel"),
        index = this.rowIndex + 1;

    $(this).find(".picturePriority").text(index);

    SetPicturePriority(rel, index);
});
```

Comment: Yes! var rel = $(this).find("a").first().attr("rel") is what i wanted, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can get id like this

```
var id =$(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: i still cant figure out how i can select the rel attr on the <a> element

Comment: There's no id attribute on the `tr` elements, but if there was, there's no real reason to use `.attr()` to get the `id`. It's much faster and simpler to just do `this.id`